# Collapsing toolbar only programmatically

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, toolbar, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

How to allow the toolbar to collapse only programmatically, through setExpanded(false), but not through scrolling? I want to disable to collapse through scrolling. I need help, my friends

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`appBarLayout.setExpanded`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/appbar/AppBarLayout#setexpanded) method to collapse/expand the toolbar:

```
//Collapse the toolbar with animation
appBarLayout.setExpanded(false,true);
```

To disable the nested scrolling you can use in the nested view something like:

```
   //Vith a NestedScrollView
   nestedScrollView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
   //With a RecyclerView
   recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```